# Any Magento Class or Imnterface Alternative to Zend_Validate_Regex

Tags: magento2, zend-framework

I am Refactoring some code while doing I found `Zend_Validate_Regex` directly use in the code

```
$validator = new \Zend_Validate_Regex(['pattern' => '/^[a-z][a-z_0-9]{0,29}[a-z0-9]$/']);
```

I want suggestions from Magento Community is there any interface in Magneto Framework to use

if No, is this recommended to this class directly?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You could use this class : vendor/magento/framework/Validator/Regex.php. But it is empty and extends Zend_Validate_Regex and Magento itself do not necessarily use this class. In the core you can see a lot of validation made like this one in vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Menu/Item/Validator.php:

```
$resourceValidator = new \Zend_Validate();
        $resourceValidator->addValidator(new \Zend_Validate_StringLength(['min' => 8]));
        $resourceValidator->addValidator(
            new \Zend_Validate_Regex('/^[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]+_[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]+::[A-Za-z_0-9]+$/')
        );
```